# SharePoint Search API dead, how to achieve it in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/query-office-graph-using-gql-with-search-rest-api
As per the document, Sharepoint search API will be discontinued on August 31, 2017. I have used

> xx.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='data'&startrow=11

for "Everything" serach. and for people added param `&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'` with above url. But how can I achieve same result in

> graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/

In Microsoft graph API, they have mentioned only SharePoint sites search.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint
can someone point me the right document to search everything in SharePoint using graph API token with parameters.

Answer (score 5):

What is discontinued is using GQL in your call. For example:

```
https://<tenant_address>/_api/search/query?querytext='QUERY'&properties='GraphQuery:and(ACTOR(ME\,action\:1020)'
```

Note the **`GraphQuery`** that is part of the URL.

I don't think regular search will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use Graph API v1.0 like you mentioned. There is a beta, but it is not reliable. Here is the endpoint for searching by item name:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If you want to search by item properties, you will most likely have to iterate through items manually.